# Looking for iOS (runners) app for tracking GPS & heart frequency WHILE keeping data truly private?

Tags: running, app

I know there are tons of apps for keeping track of your running performance, but most of them seem to share data with third parties, which I really don't like!

Are there apps that respect one's wish for privacy of data but still allows you to track and analyze your runs (distance, time, heart rate etc.)? Ideally all data should be stored on my phone only and then manually exported to a pc/mac...

BTW. If it matters, I do have a POLAR H7 BLUETOOTH SMART and an iphone 6.

Answer (score 1):

Strava should cover all these items. You choose to only share data you want to share

https://www.strava.com/privacy

It also has HR monitors that will work with your iPhone

I share all my data but you can keep everything private if you want. There is a free and a paid version.

https://www.strava.com/athletes/1946042

Answer (score 1):

iSmoothrun http://www.ismoothrun.com/ is a GPS running app that has support for bluetooth heartrate sensors and does not have a built in "social network".  It allows you to export to the online service of your choice or to a data format.

The FAQ http://www.ismoothrun.com/faq.html states it supports the Polar H7